# How to run Black Duck scan through IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, open-source, code-analysis, intellij-plugin

I would like to run the Black Duck scan for my Java Maven project within IntelliJ IDEA. Are there plugins for it? I found the [hub-detect](https://github.com/blackducksoftware/hub-detect) and corresponding documentation for other [IDEs plugins such as Eclipse and Visual Studio](https://blackducksoftware.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/INTDOCS/pages/47190985/Integrated+Development+Environments) but nothing for IntelliJ IDEA. Could someone please suggest if there is any?

Answer (score 4):

There is an Intelli-j plugin named "Synopsys Code Sight" which will allow you to run Black Duck scans.  Here is the plugin site: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11516-synopsys-code-sight

Answer (score 0):

As of this day there is no official plugin for IntelliJ. However you can run detect using command (terminal) like described [here](https://github.com/blackducksoftware/synopsys-detect/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide#windows)